# SystemError: <built-in function RoutingModel_SolveWithParameters>

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I am following the [example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#dist_callback1), using `Python3.7.0`, but I got the following error:

**EDIT**
I am using `ortools Version: 7.0.6546`

```
RuntimeError: SWIG std::function invocation failed.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aenaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ortools\constraint_solver\pywrapcp.py", line 2136, in <lambda>
    __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, Assignment, name, value)
  File "C:\Users\aenaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ortools\constraint_solver\pywrapcp.py", line 71, in _swig_setattr
    return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, 0)
  File "C:\Users\aenaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ortools\constraint_solver\pywrapcp.py", line 55, in _swig_setattr_nondynamic
    if type(value).__name__ == 'SwigPyObject':
SystemError: <class 'type'> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cidy.ai\delivery-app\test.py", line 68, in <module>
    run()
  File "E:\cidy.ai\delivery-app\test.py", line 59, in run
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\aenaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ortools\constraint_solver\pywrapcp.py", line 3425, in SolveWithParameters
    return _pywrapcp.RoutingModel_SolveWithParameters(self, search_parameters, solutions)
SystemError: <built-in function RoutingModel_SolveWithParameters> returned a result with an error set
```

Could you please understand this issue?

Comment: Can you provide us the ortools version you used ? Which example did you try to run please give us the command line ?
Maybe this one https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#program1 ?

Comment: you can check the version of ortools using:
`python -m pip show ortools`
OR
`python -c "import ortools; print(ortools.__version__)"`

Comment: @Mizux version 7.0.6546

Comment: @Mizux yes the example routing/tsp

Comment: remind me the https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1022

Comment: can you give me the exact version of your python3.7 installation ?

Comment: @Mizux Python 3.7.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191148/discussion-between-mizux-and-adham-enaya).